# Error message when creating a ReactJS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

```
          npm update check failed                  │
```

│            Try running with sudo or get access            │
│           to the local update config store via            │
│ sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) C:\Users\Sava.config

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\Sava\Desktop\react-exercise\exer\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\Sava\Desktop\react-exercise\exer\node_modules\core-js
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
>
> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\Sava\Desktop\react-exercise\exer\node_modules\core-js-pure
>   node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

- cra-template@1.0.3
- react-dom@16.13.1
- react@16.13.1
- react-scripts@3.4.1
  added 1613 packages from 750 contributors and audited 921730 packages in 101.931s

58 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 1 low severity vulnerability
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

i type: npx create-react-app exer

Comment: So did you run npm audit?

Comment: No, how to run it?

Comment: read the message: found 1 low severity vulnerability run **npm audit fix** to fix them, or **npm audit** for details